# Does MassTransit support Activity / ConsolidationId on Azure?

Tags: masstransit

I'm using Application Insights (AI) to instrument my code.   AI uses Activity to provide some data.  Activity.ParentId can be used as a per-transaction identifier, across multiple services, so that a single API call can be tracked through the code, to the database and other HTTP services etc.

MassTransit has a message ConsolidationId, to track (I believe) Sagas, but I don't think it is using the Activity.ParentId.

1. Am I right?
2. How can I get MT to use the Activity.ParentId as a ConsolidationId, both as a publisher and consumer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MassTransit supports Open Telemetry, which can easily be configured to push data to Azure Application Insights.

There is a [complete sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ApplicationInsights) that shows how to configure it.

Comment: Will that also propagate the current Activity.ParentId via the Message.CorrelationId ?  I want to make sure that all the events captured are traceable to the initial event.

Comment: The message `CorrelationId` has nothing to do with telemetry, but MassTransit will add any of the envelope headers with values as tags before exporting telemetry data.

Comment: Imagine I have 2 applications.  A publisher and a consumer.  The publisher receives an API call, sets the Activity.ParentId, and publishes a message.   The consumer receives this message.   Both applications output some telemetry to AI.   Will they have the same ParentId so that they can be viewed in AI as one transaction?

Comment: Of course, that's how it works.

Comment: I'd suggest watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsTYClGrOVI).